# How can I apply oracles rownum to impala?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper, impala

I want to convert an oracle query into impala.

```
select name,class,floor
from class.students
where name = 'ted' 
and grad ='a'
and rownum<2
```

Although impala can not recognize rownum.

I tried to solve it with `group by` in the selected columns, but I think it is not correct.

Also, rownum works as a limit or it fetches the unique row in case that we have duplicates ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `limit` to mimic oracle `rownum`. You can use `offset` too to control over number of rows.
Impala `limit` doesn't de-duplicate and you need to use `distinct` to do it. Also note Impala fetches the data first and then apply `limit` unlike oracle.

```
select name,class,floor
from class.students
where name = 'ted' 
and grad ='a'
limit 2 -- This will show 2 records.
```